# Behat scripts unable to find element

Tags: php, automation, automated-tests, behat, mink

I am very new to **behat**, I have setup my machine but when I try to perform a simple option of clicking a title on the page or filling a text box the scripts says

> Form field with id|name|label|value "title" not found.
>   (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException).

Even when I am trying to verify text on the page it still gives the same error.
I am using mink framework.

[BDD file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi8nu.png)

[Code it is pointing to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24mLN.png)

[behat file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPJQv.png)

[Page DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8BWk.png)

Please help as I am really stuck.

Comment: What frameworks/languages are you using? Could you post a stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @MaartenDev : I am using Mink and the error stated in the main question is the error I am getting on Terminal.

Comment: Could you post the code section which uses the mink library? The error indicates that your selector couldn't find an element with an attribute value of title. @TroubledByBehat

Comment: @MaartenDev I am using the preloaded BDD steps of Mink, I am not writing any code. Sorry if i am being too thick. I have attached screenshot of the step definition which is in Mink library to the original question

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, are you sure the application url is configured correctly in behat? is `/application/` available? @TroubledByBehat. Could you show what is configured in `behat.yml`?

Comment: @MaartenDev Yes, I can see the script going to the required url after starting a browser. Attached above

Comment: Did you annotate(place above) the Scenario with `@javascript`? @TroubledByBehet

Comment: @MaartenDev No, i did not.

Comment: Can you try adding that annotation and running it again?

Comment: I did but no luck. I also tried to search "Hello" on google but still the same result.@MaartenDev

Comment: Did you run the selenium server? `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar`? @TroubledByBehat

Comment: Yup already running. It goes to the required URL but is then unable to find the elements.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of the dom you are trying to access? @TroubledByBehat?

Comment: attached to the main question @MaartenDev

Comment: @MaartenDev: I managed to resolve the issue by downgrading my Selenium server and it worked. Thanks for all your help, much appreciated

Comment: Ah nice! Glad you solved it! These issues waste so much unnecessary time!

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my selenium server from 3.14 to 2.5 and it resolved the issue. With 3.14 when I check the browser was fired but the page was not returning 200.